# Name in a single line in moderncv

Tags: moderncv

I would like that my full name in the CV appears in a single line, I am using
`\firstname{manuel}
\familyname{fernandez-perez}` 
also my email is too long and it automatically splits it in two lines and I would still want one, I am using `\email{}` thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: I am using the template.tex in http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples (with the variation of green, classic)

Comment: This question is improved at the next question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82167/align-names-data-and-picture-in-cv , which leads to a better result.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To solve the first problem you can change `\makecvtitlenamewidth` (in moderncv 2.0 `\makecvheadnamewidth`) (default=`10cm`) and/or reduce the font size used for the name (the example below uses both changes); for the second issue, to avoid a possible overlap between the name and the personal information, instead of using `\email`, I used the `\extrainfo` field, but with the necessary provision to make it functional as the original `\email` field:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic} 
\moderncvcolor{green}

\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{12cm}
\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{24}{29}\mdseries\upshape}

\firstname{Manuel} 
\familyname{Fern\'andez-P\'erez}
\title{CV}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}
\mobile{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone{+2~(345)~678~901}
\fax{+3~(456)~789~012}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\extrainfo{\emailsymbol\emaillink{manuel@fernandez-perez-galdos.com}}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle
\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  \cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In a comment, a new request was made to shift the name upwards; the file `moderncvstyleclassic.sty`, responsible for the `classic` style settings, uses (in the definition of `\makecvtitle`) a `tabular` and a `minipage` with bottom alignment (`[b]` in the optional argument) to typeset the name and the personal information, respectively; one option then is to use the `etoolbox` command to patch `\makecvtitle` and change `[b]` to `[t]` (now that the name has been shifted, using `\email` is again possible without overlapping):

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\moderncvstyle{classic} 
\moderncvcolor{green}

\patchcmd{\makecvtitle}{[b]}{[t]}{}{}
\patchcmd{\makecvtitle}{[b]}{[t]}{}{}

\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{12cm}
\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{24}{29}\mdseries\upshape}

\firstname{Manuel} 
\familyname{Fern\'andez-P\'erez}
\title{CV}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}
\mobile{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone{+2~(345)~678~901}
\fax{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{manuel@fernandez-perez-galdos.com}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle
\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  \cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The name can then be lowered at will, by using the above modifications and something like

```
 \firstname{\texorpdfstring{\\[1ex]Manuel}{Manuel}}
```

Comment: I have this problem: ! Undefined control sequence 1.3 \moderncvcolor{green} I guess I have to download some package?

Comment: @inquisitor seems like your `moderncv` package is outdated. You can get the newest version from CTAN: [moderncv](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/moderncv).

Comment: Now it works, thanks. How can I do to put the name in the upper left corner? I mean upper than it is now

Comment: @inquisitor please see my updated answer.

Comment: sorry but I cannot make it to work when I include `\photo[64pt]{picture}` the picture appears higher up in the right up corner and I would like that the name and personal data to be at the same height

Comment: Note that in moderncv 2.0 the length `makecvtitlenamewidth` was apparently renamed to `makecvheadnamewidth`.